# Is the "Bigger is not always better" correct?

Tags: grammar

During a conversation with my friend, I said

> I have a big house

He replied

> Bigger is not always better

Shouldn't he have said

> Big is not always good

since there's no comparison in what I said?

Comment: _Bigger is not always better_ sounds more natural and idiomatic. The comparison can be deduced from the context.

Comment: Shouldn't it be big is not always better...

Comment: *Bigger isn't always better* is the most natural way to express this. *Xer is Yer*, with its negative *Xer is not (always) Yer*, is a stock construction in English and has an almost proverbial ring.

Comment: Havent you heard that song big is better by alex gopher? 

Comment: @user236989 - You seem skeptical. Forget the song; [behold the ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+is+good%2Cbig+is+better%2Cbigger+is+better&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15). _Bigger is better_ is better.

Answer (score 4):

Think of it this way:

> [A house that's] **bigger** [than your current house] is not always better [than the current size of your house].

The comparison in "bigger is not always better" is between what you said ("I have a big house") and what your friend was saying could be better (a smaller house).